# How to make clang compile to llvm IR

Tags: c, clang, llvm, bitcode

I want clang to compile my C/C++ code to LLVM bitcode rather than a binary executable. How can I achieve that?

And if I have the LLVM bitcode, how can I further compile it to a binary executable?

I want to add some of my own code to the LLVM bitcode before compiling to a binary executable.

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Given some C/C++ file `foo.c`:

```
> clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c
```

Produces `foo.ll` which is an LLVM IR file.

The `-emit-llvm` option can also be passed to the compiler front-end directly, and not the driver by means of `-cc1`:

```
> clang -cc1 foo.c -emit-llvm
```

Produces `foo.ll` with the IR. `-cc1` adds some cool options like `-ast-print`. Check out `-cc1 --help` for more details.

---

To compile LLVM IR further to assembly, use the `llc` tool:

```
> llc foo.ll
```

Produces `foo.s` with assembly (defaulting to the machine architecture you run it on). `llc` is one of the LLVM tools - [here is its documentation](http://llvm.org/cmds/llc.html).

Comment: What does -S do here?

Comment: @meawoppl: -S like in gcc says emit textual assembly rather than assembled binary

Comment: Ahha.  I was having a hard time finding anything in the docs about it.  It is safe to assume that many flags in clang mirror gcc flag structure?

Comment: @EliBendersky Do you know how to compile multiple .c and .h files into one human readable IR so that I can run the IR using 'lli theIrFile'? Thanks

Comment: @cache: compile each into its own IR file and then use the LLVM linker to combine

Comment: Bitcode files can be compiled with `clang` directly (omitting `llc`). `llc` has different cmdline flags and different pipeline so normally it's more of an annoyance.

Comment: For anyone that needs llvm bytecode in a cmake project: `-emit-llvm` can't be used in `CLANG_CXX_FLAGS`, because clang crashes if the flag is passed for linking. I used `-save-temps` instead, which did not break anything. Note that this does not create `.ll` files and requires using `llvm-dis` to translate `.bc` to `.ll`.

Answer (score 30):

If you have multiple source files, you probably actually want to use link-time-optimization to output one bitcode file for the entire program.  The other answers given will cause you to end up with a bitcode file for every source file.

Instead, you want to compile with link-time-optimization

```
clang -flto -c program1.c -o program1.o
clang -flto -c program2.c -o program2.o
```

and for the final linking step, add the argument -Wl,-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm

```
clang -flto -Wl,-plugin-opt=also-emit-llvm program1.o program2.o -o program
```

This gives you *both* a compiled program and the bitcode corresponding to it (program.bc).  You can then modify program.bc in any way you like, and recompile the modified program at any time by doing

```
clang program.bc -o program
```

although be aware that you need to include any necessary linker flags (for external libraries, etc) at this step again.

Note that you need to be using the gold linker for this to work.  If you want to force clang to use a specific linker, create a symlink to that linker named "ld" in a special directory called "fakebin" somewhere on your computer, and add the option

```
-B/home/jeremy/fakebin
```

to any linking steps above.

Comment: Apparently `also-emit-llvm` was removed

Answer (score 25):

If you have multiple files and you don't want to have to type each file, I would recommend that you follow these simple steps (I am using `clang-3.8` but you can use any other version):

1. generate all `.ll` files

   ```
   clang-3.8 -S -emit-llvm *.c
   ```
2. link them into a single one

   ```
   llvm-link-3.8 -S -v -o single.ll *.ll
   ```
3. (Optional) Optimise your code (maybe some alias analysis)

   ```
   opt-3.8 -S -O3 -aa -basicaaa -tbaa -licm single.ll -o optimised.ll
   ```
4. Generate assembly (generates a `optimised.s` file)

   ```
   llc-3.8 optimised.ll
   ```
5. Create executable (named `a.out`)

   ```
   clang-3.8 optimised.s
   ```

Comment: Your solution is quite unique:  you used "-S" instead of just leaving it as binary output.   Is there any difference between having "-S" and not having "-S"?

Comment: @PeterTeoh I use the `-S` option (in step 2), I specify that I would like to produce the output in LLVM IR. Basically, put all *.ll files into a single one. I do this to check that the optimisations really change the code, i.e. `single.ll` and `optimised.ll` should now look different (code-wise) and you could also show the report to see if there is any difference at all.

Comment: `-basicaaa` is a wrong flag, `-basicaa` must be used instead.

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
clang -emit-llvm -o foo.bc -c foo.c
clang -o foo foo.bc
```

Comment: I'd recommend to keep extension meanings intact. IOW, `.o` should refer to binary object files, `.s` to assembly files, and something else (by convention `.ll`) to LLVM IR files. Otherwise it's easy to get confused. Clang/LLVM now have no linker of their own for binary objects (though one is in the works). The LLVM linker `llvm-ld` just joins several IR files into one

Comment: @EliBendersky: you're correct where file extensions are concerned - and the clang frontend actually does the right thing if `.bc` is used; also, keep in mind that `llvm-ld` can act as frontend for the system toolchain, ie my previous answer using `llvm-ld -native` should work as expected....

Comment: @rickfoosusa: works for me - `foo.bc` is an LLVM bitcode file

Comment: Works for me: `clang -emit-llvm -o test.bc -c test.c && file test.bc: test.bc: LLVM IR bitcode`.

Answer (score 14):

Did you read [`clang` documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) ? You're probably looking for `-emit-llvm`.