# Writing Complete analysis using llvm-clang

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I have following tasks that I need to do as part of my research idea:

1. Parse the C file(s) at hand to get llvm-IR.
2. Do analysis on the IR. Possibly add and remove some instructions or BB 
3. Emit either x86 executable or C (need to decide later)

I think this is quite common task for any one writing analysis on C, I want to do all these tasks in C/C++ (as most of our research code is in C/C++). I googled a lot, although lot of documentation is available on Tasks 2 and 3, **but less is available on Task 1, any idea on this would be really helpful.**

I want to hook these tasks as a pipe line, any suggestion for this are also welcome.

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(1) can be done by [using Clang to emit LLVM IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148890/how-to-make-clang-compile-to-llvm-ir).

(2) can be done by [writing your own LLVM pass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html), and later invoking it (with any other passes you're interested in) via [LLVM's opt tool](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html).

(3) (to x86) can be done by [LLVM's llc tool](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html).

All of these are also accessible as APIs, not only command-line tools, making it possible to incorporate into your pipe.