# What is the flag on clang to print the IR code

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, flags

I need a flag for the clang compiler that prints the IR code generated on the front end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make clang compile to llvm IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148890/how-to-make-clang-compile-to-llvm-ir)

Comment: To print the result to the screen rather than into a file, you can use `-o -`.

Answer (score 0):

To print the IR into the stdout you can use:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm -o - file.c
```