# How to compile C to LLVM IR in the browser with WASM?

Tags: javascript, c, llvm, webassembly

I see through [How to make clang compile to llvm IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148890/how-to-make-clang-compile-to-llvm-ir) that you can generate LLVM IR from C like this:

```
clang -S -emit-llvm foo.c
```

Which produces `foo.ll` as an LLVM IR-containing file.

I see two WASM projects:

- https://github.com/soedirgo/llvm-wasm
- https://github.com/tbfleming/cib (clang wasm in browser, with [demo](https://tbfleming.github.io/cib/) of some sort).

However, those seem to be *running* the WASM in the browser. I would simply like to generate LLVM IR in the browser, and show the text of the LLVM IR and that's it, using probably the clang compiler. How can I do that? I haven't yet built my own `.wasm` file and implemented a wasm npm module before, but I have gotten imagemagick-wasm to work in the browser, which is neat, so I'm new.

What are the steps I need to take to get LLVM IR to be generated from C code in the browser? [This](https://depth-first.com/articles/2019/10/16/compiling-c-to-webassembly-and-running-it-without-emscripten/) (for example) shows how to compile a basic C program into WASM and run it in the browser.

Some C:

```
// add.c
int add (int first, int second)
{
  return first + second;
}
```

the CLI command:

```
clang --target=wasm32 --no-standard-libraries -Wl,--export-all -Wl,--no-entry -o add.wasm add.c
```

The browser:

```
const response = await fetch('add.wasm');
const bytes = await response.arrayBuffer();
const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes);

console.log('The answer is: ' + instance.exports.add(1, 2));
```

So that explains how to get the `.wasm` file and use it in the browser. But I'm still not sure about a few things.

Main things I'm unsure about:

1. How do you know what the JS API is going to be for a large library like the clang compiler? I know for example the [`ffmpeg.wasm`](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) project simply has an `ffmpeg = new FFmpeg; ffmpeg.exec(argsArray)` API to basically run the CLI in the browser. But most other libraries do like that `add` function above and have an API derived from the C API. So will I have a `clang.exec(['-target=wasm32', '--no-standard-libraries', '-Wl', ...])` sort of API in the end, or how will I know what the API is in JS?
2. And the crux of it, what will be the API for this specific command, so I can get text of the LLVM IR in the browser directly? It writes to a file on the CLI, so is there going to be an in-memory file system I need to read from or something? Not sure how to mentally translate from the clang CLI to the browser JS API.
3. Can I take advantage of either of those two linked libraries above? Or should I use emscripten to somehow build llvm or clang libraries into wasm on my own? Any tips in that direction would be very helpful as well, if necessary to do it on my own.

If I *have* to boil it down to just 1 question, here it is:

*How do I generate LLVM IR using clang or llvm libraries and compiling them to `.wasm`?*

Comment: Do you want to show the text of the LLVM IR or run the code? In the former case you don't want WASM, in the latter you do.

Comment: Yes I just want the text of the LLVM IR code, like that `emit-llvm` command. Why don't I need WASM in that case? I need to run `clang` in the browser, so I thought compile it to WASM.

Comment: You would have to port clang to WASM, which is probably going to be a nightmare... I see [this project](https://github.com/binji/wasm-clang) that claims to have done it but I don't know if/how it works, maybe you can figure it out. If you have a server though, I think you are much better off making your JS code ask your server to compile code for you and then display the results (like godbolt.org does).

Comment: clang in the browser sounds impractical to me. What are you trying to achieve? Are you certain you really have to compile C?

Comment: I wanted to avoid any server interaction if possible, it is a security feature.

Answer (score 2):

godbolt can do this, https://godbolt.org

Put your C code in the left window, choose a clang compiler e.g. MinGW Clang 16.0.2 and add your options next to the compiler `-S -emit-llvm`.  You can then see the IR.

[image]

E.g.
https://godbolt.org/z/hzxf983fj

Comment: goldbolt runs the compiler on a server, I think, not in the browser.

Comment: true, so this answer doesn't comply with "run clang in the browser" in the comments above.